# Reading eml file in java : base64 issue

Tags: java, base64, jakarta-mail, mime-message

I have problem while i ma trying to read eml file.
My code is

```
InputStream inMsg = new FileInputStream("D:\\Sample Project\\makhir.eml");
   Message msg = new MimeMessage(session, inMsg);
    if(msg.isMimeType("multipart/*") || msg.isMimeType("MULTIPART/*")){
             Multipart mp = (Multipart)msg.getContent();
             int totalAttachments = mp.getCount();
             if(totalAttachments>0){
             for(int i=0;i<totalAttachments;i++){
               Part part = mp.getBodyPart(i);
               String attachFileName = part.getFileName();
               String disposition = part.getDisposition();
               String contentType = part.getContentType();
               if((attachFileName!=null &&  attachFileName.endsWith(".ics"))`||contentType.indexOf("text/calendar")>=0){
        String[] dateHeader = msg.getHeader("date");
             }
        }
           inMsg.close();
         }
```

Here i am not getting value in `part.getFileName()` and all other value.
Here is my email content.

Comment: Could you post the contents of `makhir.eml`? Mabye the MIME part doesn't specify a file name, etc.

Comment: First thanks for your interest Philipp..

Comment: Where? There's no content or link to it.

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626722/read-text-file-of-email-convert-to-javamail-mimemessage)! 
Your question is duplicated with that article.